# Copy the conditional formatting row wise

Tags: excel

I have 3 rows

[image]

I apply a conditional formatting to the first row, how do I copy this to the second and the third row.
The only way I know is by using paste special, but it would take a lot of effort if there are more rows, is there an easier way to copy conditional formatting row wise?

Answer (score 1):

Mark the rows before you apply the rule or change "Applies to" afterwards by typing or highlighting the desired range.

[image]